# Can't change Github account for Careers 2.0

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

My careers profile: (outdated link)

When I click on octocat to add Github project I can't (maybe don't know how) change my Github account there. Is it possible? Or do I have to make request to drop currently assigned one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve removed your saved GitHub credentials – please log out of GitHub and Careers completely and then try it again. (For best results, just open an incognito/private browsing window.)

Send a note to matt@stackoverflow.com if any problems.

Comment: thank you, but why can't I do it myself? just personal interest

Comment: It’s a feature we haven’t built – a single account is the main use case for most people. But we may add it at some point.

Comment: Can you please remove mine too. I created a new organization to separate serious repositories relevant for others from repositories that I forked just to play similar. I want only this new organization in SO career. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Never mind, I solved it by revoking access on GitHub for careers.stackoverflow.com and reconnect.